# Does Octoprint stop printing on Crash Detection?

Tags: prusa-i3, octoprint

A corner of my model curled up, causing the head to crash into it.  The Prusa MK3 detected the error, printed a message to that effect, and moved the print head to the home position.

I was surprised when printing immediately resumed, and of course immediately went awry as it pulled the model off the print bed and dragged it around.

My questions:

- Is it expected that printing stops when a head crash is detected?
- If so, does Octoprint recognize this condition and stop printing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing precisely how the crash detection should work on the Prusa Mk3, so it is doing exactly what it should do. If you look into [this video from Jozef Prusa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDJq0WplXb0&feature=youtu.be&t=145) you will see him explaining that in case a crash is detected (steps missed are registered because the Mk3 uses trinamic stepper drivers), the print head is homed and will immediately restart printing.

Please do read [this interesting post](https://shop.prusa3d.com/forum/others-archive--f66/octoprint-with-mk3-crash-detection-missed-lines-of-t15123.html); it describes your similar problems: after detection it resumes. He noteworthy mentions that even a few lines of G-code went missing, this is probably caused by the fact that OctoPrint buffers a few commands or something that get lost because the Pruse Mk3 crash fail safe kicks in.

In effect, OctoPrint is just a simple supplier of G-code commands and does not recognize the problem to act on it and will therefore continue sending new commands after the Prusa Mk3 crash has recovered (sending `ok` to OctoPrint for receiving new commands) from the crash and re-homed and got the temperatures back to normal levels.

An existing plugin for OctoPrint may help you in this case. The [Action Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/actiontrigger/) is able to detect events, but have to be implemented in your firmware. E.g. the action for filament [describes](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/actiontrigger/):

> This trigger will pause the print and home the X and Y axis, giving
>   the user the opportunity to change out the filament. The print needs
>   to be resumed manually through the UI.

Maybe it can be configured to pick up the existing event and issue a pause. It could be worth looking into this.

---

**EDIT**
Looking closer to the ActionTrigger plugin I noticed that you cannot configure it and the "manual" is very terse. I guess this might involve some serious hacking...